# Change Color of WebGL Earth Globe?

Tags: webgl-globe

I'm creating a website with an open-source globe found on the WebGL Earth site. The JavaScript code for this globe can be found here:

http://www.webglearth.com/v2/api.js

I want to alter the colors shown on the globe: the blue water, the tan land, and the purplish text/borders. Although I tried to sift through the code to find where these colors are chosen, I can't seem to find it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!